# Controlling the line height for Inkscape text?

Tags: inkscape

Is it possible to set the line height for Inkscape text in the event that we have text on multiple lines within the same text object?

This is a screenshot of my text tool:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. When you use the Text Tool, the line height/line spacing is set in the Tool Controls Bar along the top.  Confusingly, it's called "Spacing between baselines".

[image]

Comment: I'm running Inkscape 0.92.  Do you know if it's available in this version?  I only see `Spacing between letters`, `Spacing between words`, `Horizontal Kerning`, `Vertical Shift`, and `Character rotation`.

Comment: I can confirm that my version 0.92 on Windows 7 has the same presentation (A over A) with a data field to the right. Mine is set to mm rather than percent, but works as expected.

Comment: @Ole The screenshot is from Inkscape 0.92

Comment: Hmmm maybe it's different for Ubuntu.  I took a screenshot of my desktop and I don't have the A/A (A over A).

Comment: @Ole I can see it in your screenshot. It's set to 1.25

Comment: Additionally, if it doesn't work as expected, read on here: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/0.92#Line_Spacing

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks!  I see it now - I was looking over by the other text tool boxes ... :)